# Jaspersoft Studio - Oracle JDBC Data Adapter - Set Specific Schema as Current Schema

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jasper-reports, ojdbc, jaspersoft-studio

I have the latest version of Jaspersoft Studio and I am using **Oracle**'s JDBC data adapter (ojdbc11.jar), but the connection is made with the default schema, while I want the queries of each report to be executed in another schema (let's call it that: "MySchema").

For example a report with this SELECT clause will **not** work:

```
select *
from myTable
```

while a report with this SELECT clause will work:

```
select *
from MySchema.myTable
```

I tried things like this:

[image]

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.1.1.55:1521/DOMAIN.COM;connectionProperties={currentSchema=MySchema}
```

or this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.1.1.55:1521/DOMAIN.COM;connectionProperties={CURRENT_SCHEMA=MySchema}
```

or this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.1.1.55:1521/DOMAIN.COM?searchpath=MySchema
```

or this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.1.1.55:1521/DOMAIN.COM??currentSchema=MySchema
```

but without success.

Do you have a solution in this direction or do you know of any other way to solve the problem?

This is an extremely big problem if you consider that I have reports that make selects to dozens of tables and functions.